# How can I return a certain object based on what its ID is set to in the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm creating a game within Java and i'm currently implementing the amount of lives the player has. At the start they have 5 (this is shown as a frog on the screen, each frog = 1 life, lose a life = one frog is removed from the screen).

I've created a class called Life which takes in the image for the life and its x and y positions. If the player dies, a frog is supposed to be removed from the screen.

I've managed to do this by creating 5 new Life objects and giving them different names i.e. life1, life2 etc. and then removing them using their given names during the object instantiation, but it's very inefficient as i'm just chaining if statements together.

I was thinking of giving each new frog an ID within the constructor from 1 to 5, and then having a while loop which will remove the lives if the player dies (which would be the condition) and a counter decrementing from 5 to 1, however, for this to work, I would somehow need to get the separate Life objects, so something like this (in pseudocode):

```
numOfLives = 5;
while (i < numOfLives)
{
  life = Life.getLifeFromID(numOfLives);
  background.removeLife(life);
  numOfLives--;
}
```

So is it possible to create a method such as this? (written in pseudocode, i'm not entirely sure how you would specify this in actual code)

```
public Life getLifeFromID(int id)
{
     return specific Life object based on ID from argument
}
```

So if `numOfLives = 4` , the line `life = Life.getLifeFromID(numOfLives);` would be assigned the Life object of 4, which can then be removed in the next line.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that i understand your goals, have you considered adding `event` handling to your objects and then have a single controller monitor events and then remove them at the appropriate time.  That is much better than polling inside a loop.

Comment: I haven't no. I think I've got this kind of thing now if I understand correctly, the code for actually removing the life is within a timer which runs for the entire game and continuously checks if certain conditions are true (e.g. if the score has changed, if the game is in the final state so that the end alert can be popped up, and now i've a condition which is executed if the player dies

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put your Life instances into a List, then when you lose a life, you just need to remove from List with specific index.

Comment: Yeh that'd work I think, not sure why I didn't think of that earlier tbh lol thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a game too that uses a system to reference objects based on an ID.

You can start by giving 'Life' a variable called ID or whatever else you want to call it and add it to the constructor.

here is an example where I use entities in a game world.

```
for (int i = 0; i < spawnLimit; i++) {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 200) + 10;
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * 200) + 10;
        entities.add(new Entity(x, y, this.width, this.height, world_scale, , entityCount));
        entityCount += 1;
}
```

and then when you want to get an object based on the ID:

```
return entities.get(id);
```